# Why does it say undefined when i console.log()?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning javascript. I am having undefined error.
How can I take user input from HTML form and save it in javascript as global variable that can be used throughout the entire javascript?

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>sort</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src1/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input id="input" type="text" value="" ><br>
    </form>
    <button type="button" name ="button" onclick="saveinput()" >submit</button>    
    <script src = "src1/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript code:

```
var i;
function saveinput(){
  i = document.getElementById("input").value;

}
console.log(i)
```

Comment: Move `console` statement inside `function` definition (after setting value of `i`) then you will see the value once you will click the button.

Comment: Yes but what if i want to use variable i outside function?

Answer (score 1):

Put Your `console.log()` inside your function otherwise it would run first and prints `undefined`.

The value of `i` is undefined until `saveinput` function is called.

```js
var i;
function saveinput(){
  i = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
 <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input id="input" type="text" value="" ><br>
    </form>
    <button type="button" name ="button" onclick="saveinput()" >submit</button>
```

Comment: I want to use variable i outside function. How can i do that?

Comment: @pratik you must click `submit` in order the `i` to get a value otherwise it will be undefined. Unless if you set a default value.